# Creating a security exception for a self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, debian, self-signed

I have a Debian box that I would like to talk to a remote server over SSL.  The remote server has a self-signed certificate.  How can I instruct my local machine to create a permanent security exception for the remote machine?

Note: I need a command line method for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method I found for doing this is based on material at http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/

Step 1: get the cert

use the get-cert.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# usage: retrieve-cert.sh remote.host.name [port]
#
REMHOST=$1
REMPORT=${2:-443}

echo |\
openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT} 2>&1 |\
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

get the certificate file and save it in /usr/lib/ssl/certs with a .pem extension

Step 2: generate a hash for the cert

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# usage: certlink.sh filename [filename ...]

for CERTFILE in $*; do
  # make sure file exists and is a valid cert

  test -f "$CERTFILE" || continue
  HASH=$(openssl x509 -noout -hash -in "$CERTFILE")
  test -n "$HASH" || continue

  # use lowest available iterator for symlink
  for ITER in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    test -f "${HASH}.${ITER}" && continue
    ln -s "$CERTFILE" "${HASH}.${ITER}"
    test -L "${HASH}.${ITER}" && break
  done
done
```

run the certlink.sh script on the file you downloaded in step 1 and then you are done.

The location of the cert files may vary with your operating system.

Comment: What this is basically doing is obtaining the Certificate Authority certificate from the remote host that has the self-signed cert and adding it to the list of trusted certificate authorities on *YOUR* host.

Comment: Correct. And that's what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add the remote server and its key to the list of known hosts?